# Jeditable + JmaskedInput + new dynamic field

Tags: jquery, jeditable, html-table

Ok,

i'm using jeditable + jmaskedinput to manipulate my table.

```
$(".edit_user").editable("save.php", { 

                    data: '{"84":"Test User","85":"Test User"," ":" "}',

                    type: "select",

                    onblur: "submit",



                });
```

Right after this i want to add a new column to my table.

```
$('table.schichtplan tr:first').append('<th><div class="add_user" id="xyz">User</div></th>');
```

I call this above via a button ;)

So i add a new TH-Element but i cant edit it via jeditable.

My Code:

```
        $(".edit_employee").editable("save.php", { 

                data: some json,

                type: "select",

                onblur: "submit",

                placeholder: "Mitarbeiter"

            });



        $('#add_employee').click(function(){

            var tage = $('table.schichtplan tr').length-4;

            var sort_id = $('table.schichtplan').find('tr')[0].cells.length-1;

            var new_th = '<th><div id="plan_id:'+plan_id+';sort_id:'+sort_id+'" class="edit_employee">Mitarbeiter</div></th>';

            $('table.schichtplan tr:first').append(new_th);

        });
```

That's the order i use. mh

Edit:

```
   $('th > div').live('mouseenter',function(){

                $(this).editable("save.php", { 

                    data: json,

                    type: "select",

                    onblur: "submit",

                    placeholder: "Mitarbeiter"

                });

            });
```

Even this doesn't work ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `.editable()` is using `.bind()`, which only affects elements that already exist in the DOM. Try the following approach:

```
$('th > div').live('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).editable(...);
});
```

Essentially, it observes the `mouseenter` event on any `th > div`. When it happens, it makes the `div` element editable.

Comment: I tried this, doesn't work ;(
When I call the .append() part i have to "reload" .editable?

So just add the complete edit_user.editable part to the .append() part?

Comment: hum...i might not have understood your question. do you add the column at a button click?

Comment: yes, the column is added (just a new th-element). i've added more code to my first posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, with an element having `class="edit"`:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.edit', function() {
    $(this).editable('updatedata.php');
});
```